# Boosting documents in Solr based on the vote count

Tags: solr

I have a field in my schema which holds the number of votes a document has. How can I boost documents based on that number?

Something like the one which has the maximum number has a boost of 10, the one with the smallest number has 0.5 and in between the values get calculated automatically.

What I do now is this, but it doesn't give the desired results:

```
recip(rord(vote_count),1,1000,1000)^10.0
```

Thanks.

Comment: There's a way (can't remember off the top of my head) to see how scores are calculated. Something like debug=true. Can you supply us with the printout of the scoring? I've found with boosts that sometimes you have to twiddle with them. They aren't quite as strong as you think.

Answer (score 0):

i tend to build my indexes using raw lucene, in which case it is extremely easy,

```
doc.setBoost(boost_val);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just starting on this and it looks like either a linear boost or log based boost will help most: i.e. log(votecount)^10 (don't forget ^10 means boost times 10, not to the tenth power.